# FTP to unix server using mainframe job

Tags: unix, ftp, mainframe

I need to write a mainframe job to FTP a dataset to temp folder then move that file from the temp folder to another folder with different file name. I know how to put a file to directory, but I do not know how to rename this to different folder on remote unix system.

Your help is appreciated here. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First upload the file to the correct directory, and then use the `rename` FTP command to rename it.

Comment: Thansk you,  I have used rename command and uploaded to destiantion directory successfully